# Rails rspec controller test is returning an unknown hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a very simple controller that looks like this.

```
module Veterinarians
  module Dictionaries
    class SpecialitiesController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      skip_before_action :check_current_vet, only: %i( index )

      def index
        @specialities = Veterinarians::Speciality.all
        respond_with(@specialities)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have an rspec controller test that looks like this.

```
require 'rails_helper'

Rails.describe Veterinarians::Dictionaries::SpecialitiesController, type: :controller do
  # Not returning a response body in JSON when testing RSPEC (https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/32)
  render_views true

  routes { Veterinarians::Engine.routes }

  let(:user) { double :user, id: 123 }
  before { sign_in(user) }

  context '#index' do
    let(:speciality) { double :speciality, id: :some_id, value: :some_val }

    before { allow(Veterinarians::Speciality).to receive(:all).and_return [speciality] }

    subject { get :index, format: :json }

    it { is_expected.to have_http_status(:ok) }
    it { expect(JSON.parse(subject.body)).to include('id' => 'some_id', 'value' => 'some_val') }
  end
end
```

The second example fails with this error.

`expected [{"__expired" => false, "name" => "speciality"}] to include {"id" => "some_id", "value" => "some_val"}`

Any hints as to why this would fail and where the hash with "__expired" is coming from?

I have other tests that are using this same method of testing that are successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is coming from RSpec's internal representation of a double:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/test_double.rb#L10

RSpec's doubles sometimes don't work well alongside Rails. Try instantiating a real `Speciality` instance, or using something like FactoryGirl to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Rails winds up calling `to_json` on the double. You haven't stubbed that method on the double, so the `to_json` method rails adds to `Object` is called.

This [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb) just dumps the instance variables of the object, which in this case is the internal state of the test double.

You could stub `to_json` on the double, although your spec wouldn't be testing a whole lot at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You should use factories for creating your test data. Two most popular ones are FactoryGirl or FactoryBot.

Example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "name#{n}@example.com" }
    password 'password'
  end
end
```

The `sequence(:email)` will create you a different email for each user. More details can be found [here](https://kolosek.com/rspec-controller-test/).